# Type safety and enforcement in JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to the world of javascript. I'm used to strictly typed languages, however I'm trying to get into javascript and jquery. Imagine I have a large set of scripts or functions and I want to avoid the use of anonymous classes. Is there an elegant way to enforce that parameter 'e' needs to be a 'div' object or some JQuery version of that?

```
var CORE = {
    onReady: function(){
        $("#generate").click(ELEM.genClick($("#quote")))
    },
    //...
};

var ELEM = {
     genClick: function(e){
         // e must be div!
     },
     //...
};

$(document).ready(CORE.onReady());
```

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: What's an anonymous class?

Comment: Btw, it needs to be `$(document).ready(CORE.onReady);` and `$("#generate").click(function(e) { ELEM.genClick($("#quote"));})`

Comment: This isn't wrong persay, but generally the convention would be that "e" as an argument passed to a function will refer to an event. Especially one named "genClick", the expectation would be that its a click event

Comment: Is your genClick function returning another function? I find it confusing as traditionally 'e' variable names are short for 'event' and wouldn't ever be a DOM element.

Comment: Your worry about type safety is a moot point in JS in my opinion. Not to mention you lock yourself out of many awesome features of JS. Testing also becomes slightly more cumbersome when you try to strictly type everything.

Comment: Ah, no e is not an event sorry. That's the lack of experience.

Comment: Can you explain why it needs to be a `<div>`? You can put assertions in your code, but that's not what you normally do it in a dynamically typed language. Please provide the code of the `genClick` function.

Comment: `genClick` loads a page using ajax into the div supplied. I've gone ahead and done it differently. I've used an anonymous class under `CORE.onReady`. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `e` is a `<div>`:

```
e instanceof HTMLDivElement // implies e instanceof HTMLElement
// OR
e.nodeType === 1 && e.tagName === 'DIV'
```

Comment: This is vanilla js, if you want to do the same check in jQuery, you need to get the actual element from the jQuery object

Comment: @MichielAriens: You can use `e instanceof jQuery`, but that's an odd requirement to allow both.